# cookies are still valid after logout in superset

Tags: apache-superset, python-3.9, flask-appbuilder

We have our superset instance tested by security team.
they are performing following steps -

```
1. login into superset.
2. copy the session cookies with the help of browser extension.
3. logout from superset.
4. import session cookies into second browser.
5. hit superset login url in second browser.
```

Now Superset getting logged in second browser, It can be replicated in same browser.

Cookies are supposed be invalidated after logout.

How do I invalidate session cookies after logout in superset ? so that this scenario is avoided.

We are using LDAP for user authentication.

Comment: Here is the related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/24713) you've opened.

Comment: @SebastianLiebscher, Can you pls guide me where I should look for solution.
Yes I also raised issue on superset repo, unfortunately no response.

Comment: You can post the problem on Superset Slack or the dev mailing list to raise awareness ([have a look here](https://github.com/apache/superset/wiki)). If you are comfortable with Python, you can also try to fix the code in question and create a PR.